# My 3D prints don't end up the same as the model

Tags: 3d-models, troubleshooting, blender

I'm trying to print a very simple item that I created in blender:

[image]

However, the print always ends up being a simple "plane" with some scribbely stuff on top

Comment: Please add (by [edit] of your question) an image of the stl in a slicer software and a photo of the end-product. Please note that Blender has proven (from other questions at 3DPrinting.SE) to be not a very good tool for designing parts.

Comment: I will add the requested parts when I get back home. Can you recommend software for designing parts?

Comment: This is not a recommendations site, but if you are prepared to learn how to use Blender, maybe you should look at Fusion 360.

Comment: @Anton Let me reevaluate 0scar's note a little: Blender has been proven to be at times  problematic when it comes to creating non-manifold objects, but if used carefully can be perfectly fine to make modeling. However, for dimensional designing, you may want to use something like a CAD Program. I personally like Fusion 360, which is at times a little complicated, but have worked with Design Spark Mechanical, which is a little simpler and liked it. also, angus has one more https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cuqao90C76U&t=0s

Comment: @Anton If Fusion360 isn't your thing and you're into programing, you may feel comfortable with OpensCAD.

Comment: Sorry I did not intend to break the rules, but the conversation was going that way. My primary question really is though, that the 3d stl file that I've created looks the same in all visualizaiton softwares, and even the printer software. But the outcome is not what is represented in these programs.

Comment: Anton, you should view the results of your slicing tool in "Layer mode" . That will at least show you whether the slicing algorithm was able to interpret your STL model correctly.

Comment: "Scribbely stuff" sounds like you have a layer adhesion problem with the printer, rather than a problem with your STL file. Can you [edit] your question and include a photo of the print, and details about your printer: what printer, what material, what slicer, slicer settings, etc.